# Comparing filepaths with PHP, OS independently

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

What would be the best way to compare two filepaths with PHP?

Right now, I'm trying to do preg_match and - since windows DS would break the regex - run both patterns through `str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', $path);`

Comment: Have a look at using the [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function.

Comment: Ah yeah! Didn't even think of that.. Thanks! .. Edit: One thing just came to mind.. Wouldn't pathinfo work only with actual files?

Comment: I'm not too sure. I'd assume it would work anyway, since it doesn't appear to get any metadata from the file that isn't in the path anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you not to compare full file paths but only relative path starting at your web site root.

so just do something like this:

```
$path = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], "", $path); // this will cut your website root
if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR != "/")
   $path = str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', $path);   // replace non unix slashes
if (preg_match($yourpattern, $path))
{
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: What difference would it make to compare relative paths rather than absolute paths? Sorry for asking..

Comment: well on windows path starts with a drive letter eg: C:\inetpub\ and on unix systems with a slash of directory eg: /mnt/webroot so if you trim initial path of your web root then you prevent problems to match paths on different platforms.